# Open close dialog at top of question when reviewing on mobile

Tags: feature-request, review, vote-to-close, mobile-web, popups

When reviewing Close Votes on mobile, the close dialog pops up at the bottom of the question, which is an inconvenient location because you need to scroll down. For long questions, you can't even see the dialog opened; as you often zoom in to view the question better, it also happens on medium-sized questions.

[image]

On the desktop, the dialog opens at the top, which is much better. Yes, it covers the question body, but you hit the Close button after you've made the decision to close it, so you don't need to view the question anymore.

[image]